# Stop chrome changing file associations

Tags: google-chrome, kde, default-programs

I use Google Chrome stable occasionally, using its apt repository, on Ubuntu Eoan (19.10). When it updates, it modifies the file `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` to add itself to the defaults for many mime types. In particular, it modifies the PDF association to

```
application/pdf=org.gnome.Evince.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
```

I don't have evince installed, as I have a KDE desktop. In fact the association was previously set to

```
application/pdf=org.kde.okular.desktop;
```

This means that Firefox now opens PDF files in Chrome, rather than Okular. Is there any way to stop Chrome from modifying the `defaults.list` file, except by stopping it updating automatically?

Comment: If you use Firefox to visit https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf, Google Chrome opens to display the pdf file specified by the link?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to mention the distro you're using, as well as its version.

Comment: I have Kubuntu 18.04 and 19.10. And Firefox and Google Chrome are installed on both systems. In both Kubuntus, I've set Firefox Preferences > Applications > Preview in Firefox. And it works.

Comment: My Firefox Preference settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDNKP.png

Comment: Yes, if firefox is set to "Use default" in its application preferences. I don't like the firefox built-in PDF viewer, so had it set as default to use Okular (which was the default before chrome changed it).

Comment: Okay. I guess I'll have to wait till the next google-chrome-stable update comes along to see what happens. I usually download pdfs and so haven't noticed anything amiss.

Answer (score 0):

I have to execute this line each time chrome is updated:

sudo sh -c "cp /usr/share/applications/defaults.list /usr/share/applications/defaults_back.list && grep -v chrome /usr/share/applications/defaults_back.list > /usr/share/applications/defaults.list"